# ASP.NET MySQL Data Access Layer

Tags: asp.net, mysql, data-access-layer

I have an ASP.NET application that access a MySQL database. For that I made a class with all the queries I need to retrieve data from database.

In order to bring from database just the info I need I have a lot of queries:

example
One query that gets the NAME and DATE from the table NEWS
Another query to get the NAME, DATE AND TEXT from the table news.

I do this because in some pages I just need the name and date and in others I need also the text.

What do you think would be better for performance, just to have one query and get all the information even if I don't use some of the fields in some pages or to have a query for each case?

This has been a very simple example, in some cases I have many fields...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends more on how often you create connection with database. 
For example, if your page loads and some parts of your page use first query and other use the second, there is benefit of executing the second query for both only once and distribute data as needed. You save on unnecessary connections and this does result in performance gain. 
However if you have different pages calling different methods and you can not reduce number of calls, you can keep both methods and call the one that will select only what you need.